# Cannot display tamil, telgu, hindi data fetch from spotify API properly

Tags: python, json, api, spotify

I am trying to fetch transcript of podcast from spotify api. All the trancsript which are in english are getting correctly fetched. But transcript which are available in hindi, tamil and telgu are showing some random character like '¯à®¸à¯ à®ªà®¾à®à®¿à®à¯'. I have tried decoding it with uft-8 and iso-8859-1, but non of these things worked. All other data is getting correctly displayed. I am providing the code below. Please help me in to get these transcript (in hindi, tamil, telgu).

Code :

```
import requests

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'authorization': auth_token,
    'client-token': client_token
}


def parse_url(url):
    token = url.split("/")[-1:]
    return token

def get_api(Episode):
    print(Episode[0])
    api = f'https://api-partner.spotify.com/pathfinder/v1/query?operationName=getEpisodeOrChapter&variables=%7B%22uri%22%3A%22spotify%3Aepisode%3A{Episode[0]}%22%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%227ff3fa30afde43b3a77755849e562eaeae28d81932494a33f15d7fb62bdcd092%22%7D%7D'
    return api

## PASTE THE SPECIFIED EPISODE URL HERE
url = f'https://open.spotify.com/episode/0L2EVv6YsvZYbxuPIfev71'
## You can olso automate this: In the playslist page, scrape the episode uri from the href tags
token = parse_url(url)

api = get_api(token)
id = token[0]
print(id)
s = requests.session()
res = s.get(url)
api_response = s.get(api, headers=headers)

print(api_response.text)
my_bytes_value= api_response.content
my_json = my_bytes_value.decode('utf-8')
data = api_response.json()
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2'].keys())
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['transcripts']['items'][0].keys())
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['transcripts']['items'][0]['cdnUrl'])
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2'])
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['__typename'])
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['name'])
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['description'])
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['duration']['totalMilliseconds'])
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['releaseDate']['isoString'])
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['podcast']['name'])
print(data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['transcripts']['items'][0]['language'])
transcipt_url = data['data']['episodeUnionV2']['transcripts']['items'][0]['cdnUrl']
transcipt = s.get(transcipt_url)
trans = transcipt.content
my_trans = trans.decode('iso-8859-1')
print(my_trans)
# print(transcipt.text)
```

I am sharing the output of this code here:
[image]

Comment: Does your console support displaying these languages? Do you need to change fonts to ones that support these characters? Have you tried writing the contents to a text file as `utf-8` and then opening it in an app that reads such files?

Comment: Can you add a line `print(repr(trans[:150]))` at the end and show its output in the question?

Comment: @MichaelButscher this is the output i'm getting by print(repr(trans[:150])).b'\n\x031.0\x12&spotify:episode:0L2EVv6YsvZYbxuPIfev71\x1a\x1a2022-05-25T06:13:03.43066Z"\xcc\x05\x08\x01\x10\xde\x1b\x1a\xc4\x05\n\x8d\x02\xe0\xae\xb5\xe0\xae\xa3\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xae\xae\xe0\xaf\x8d \xe0\xae\xa8\xe0\xaf\x80\xe0\xae\x99\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xae\xb3\xe0\xaf\x8d \xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xaf\x87\xe0\xae\x9f\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\x9f\xe0\xaf\x81 '

Comment: @wkl yes I have tried these thing...but it doesnt worked.

Comment: The "trans" data seems to consist of a header of data unknown to me followed by utf-8-encoded text. For the specific data you showed in the comment the line `my_trans = trans[86:].decode('utf-8')` should produce readable content (if there isn't some other data at the end interfering with the decoding). Unfortunately the number 86 will probably not work for other requests.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I am getting this error as an output. Error : UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-571639959956> in <module>
----> 1 my_trans = trans[86:].decode('utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 316: invalid start byte

Comment: Ok, so unfortunately I can only say that the data contains utf-8-encoded text with some other data in between. A short web search didn't show a documentation for the used data format.

Comment: If you will find something usefull for this problem then please share it with me.